# As of Visual Studio 2017 15.5.1, How Does One Create a Xamarin.Forms Project to Target Minimum Android KitKat (API 19) with PCL now obsolete?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I want to know how to create a Xamarin.Forms Project that targets minimum version of Android Kitkat (API 19), without using the Shared Project option.

.Net Standard Library is not an option since [the minimum supported Android version is Nougat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard). A large percentage of my target users (more than 40%) still uses phones with an Android version lower than Nougat.

In Visual Studio 15.5.1 or greater, no PCL option is provided under the **Code Sharing Strategy Section** in creating a new Xamarin.Forms project when using the **Cross-Platform App** template.

[image]

It was noted that PCL is now deprecated on [Xamarin's Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/113198/pcl-is-missing) and also on the [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/166688/portable-class-library-pcl-missing-in-vs-2017-prof.html)

**Key Supporting Questions:**

1. With the latest Vs 2017, is PCL even still possible with Xamarin.Forms? And How?
2. If Yes, What are the steps to create a PCL-Based Xamarin.Forms Project and are there any open-soured templates to bootstrap this?
3. If No, Does this mean I can only support Android KitKat with Xamarin.Forms using the Shared-Project Code Sharing strategy/template?

Comment: Fire up VS2015, create your PCL project, open it in VS2017?

Comment: 1. Yes, but it's "deprecated", so use .NET Standard instead.
2. You can search for "Class Library (Legacy Portable)" in 2017
3. No, this has nothing to do with Android targeting.

Comment: The .Net Standard implementation support purely relates to the version of Xamarin.Android and not an Android API level. These tend to "coincide" per major releases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Forms supports Android 4.0.3 (API 15) and higher, you are confusing the  "**Target Framework**" (`compileSdkVersion`) for the "**Target Android Version**" ( `targetSdkVersion`) vs the **"Minimum Android Version"** (`minSdkVersion`).

  - Your `Xamarin.Form` project has to use the target framework of Nougat/7.0 (`MonoAndroid7.0`) or above *but* can target the minimum of 4.0.3/IceCreamSandwich version.

    - Note: The latest version of Forms required a target framework of 8.0
  - Xamarin has a great guide that explains how those things relate from Android to `Xamarin.Android`

    - [Understanding Android API Levels](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/)
- Microsoft completely removed the template option to create PCL-based libraries

  - PCL projects still build fine
  - NetStandard is the only future, PCLs are dead, etc, etc...
  - IMHO this was breaking change as a lot of my clients are not ready to convert to NetStd and there are still NetStd bugs floating around (edge cases mostly)
  - Still need to create a PCL library, grab an existing project and copy, strip and rename it... or create the `.csproj` yourself (see basic `.csproj`).

#### A Basic Profile111 PCL `.csproj`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{C38DBA87-39CB-4FD5-B409-6D19E6ED54C8}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <UseMSBuildEngine>true</UseMSBuildEngine>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>PCLTemplate</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>PCLTemplate</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile111</TargetFrameworkProfile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MyClass.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: You said I "can target the 4.0.3/IceCreamSandwich version". However, in Visual Studio 2017 I am unable to test my application on Android KitKat device or Emulator. These devices appear "Unsupported Devices" from the dropdown in VS to select a device to build/test my app on.

Comment: @Hue Set your **"Target Framework"** to `8.0`, your **"Target Android Version"** to `8.0` your **"Minimum Android Version"** to `4.0.3` Refer to the link in my answer for details

Comment: I have tried to select "Change Minimum Android Version" and changed the "Target Framework" to "Android 4.4 (Kit Kat)" this does nothing. The devices are still listed as unsupported

Comment: There is no "4.0.3" under "Target Android Version". The minimum is  Android "4.4". Have you updated to the latest version of Visual Studio when trying this?

Comment: Ok I will try those steps

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, the link explains everything well. This clears up a great deal for me. Thanks!