# Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting an error with `FirebaseInstaceIdService` to an empty class.
I dont know why and dunno how to fix it. I'm just following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERyvuOfM60g) and the  [codes](https://github.com/eddydn/XamarinFirebaseMessaging/blob/master/MyFirebaseIdService.cs) ([github project](https://github.com/eddydn/XamarinFirebaseMessaging) from video)

```
namespace MyApp
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    class MyFirebaseIdService:FirebaseInstanceIdService //<--having error with this
    {
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service md5cb05e273185b33da3bc5e66ac09d10b0.MyFirebaseIdService:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5cb05e273185b33da3bc5e66ac09d10b0.MyFirebaseIdService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/MyApp.MyApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/MyApp.MyApp-1/lib/arm, /data/app/MyApp.MyApp-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] occurred
```

Comment: Bug : https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.1/#Known_Issues

Comment: New year's coming and im still sad about many changes and bugs with vs2017

Comment: Seems you can clean/build each time as a workaround on Windows, assuming a fix will be out as a pull request was merged to fix it (rookie mistake with file zipping ;-) or downgrade your Xamarin.Android version.

Comment: Well, I've been thinking about downgrading to Visual Studio 2015, because VS 2017 Xamarin Cross Platform doesnt have a PCL option for Code sharing strategy (choosing different options give me incompatibility issues and bugs like for Microsoft.Net.Http)

Comment: You can just create one manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47957012/4984832

Comment: Thanks btw, simple clean and build did the trick.